# jQuery + PHP Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I recently upgraded jQuery from 1.8.x to 1.11.3 because of another dependency, and my autocomplete is now broken. I've been searching this site, Google, etc.. all day and cannot come up with the answer. jQuery-UI version is 1.9.2.

To start, I have a PHP file (autocomplete.php) that queries a MySQL database and returns inventory information:

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';


if ($stmt = $con->prepare("select item_no, item_desc_1, item_desc_2 FROM items")) {
$stmt->execute();

$name = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name[] = TRIM($row['item_no']) . '|' . TRIM($row['item_desc_1']) . '|' . TRIM($row['item_desc_2']);
};
echo json_encode($name);
}
?>
```

So far so good. I can check that the results are returned in the proper format.

On the page where I want the autocomplete, once the item_no is selected from the autocomplete results, item_desc_1 and item_desc_2 are populated from the results:

```
<input id="item_no" name="item_no" placeholder="Enter Item#" class="form-control" tabindex="2" type="text" />
<input id="item_desc_1" name="item_desc_1" placeholder="Enter Item Desc 1" class="form-control" type="text">
<input id="item_desc_2" name="item_desc_2" placeholder="Enter Item Desc 2" class="form-control" type="text">
```

At the very bottom of the page is my script, which should return the 3 elements from the JSON results and populate the fields.

```
$(function() {
var availableItems = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;
$("#item_no").autocomplete({
    source: availableItems.map(function(elem){
        return { 'label': elem.split('|')[0], 'value': elem.split('|')[1],'value2': elem.split('|')[2] }
    }),
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#item_no').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#item_desc_1').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#item_desc_2').val(ui.item.value2);
        return false;
    }
   });
});
```

I keep getting either Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null (Chrome) or TypeError: elem is null (Firebug).

To troubleshoot, I updated the table so there can't be NULL values in the table - if a value is NULL in either item description field then 'No Description Found' is returned. item_no is a primary key and NULL is not allowed.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did it really worked previously in the exact form you posted? For me, your 2nd Javascript line sould be `var availableItems = '<?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>';` (i.e. wrapping PHP part by quotes).

Comment: Yes, it did work. I must've removed the quotes by accident, but I tried it with them every conceivable way and I'm still getting errors.

Comment: And what if you add `console.log(availableItems);` just after its definition, then `console.log(elem);` before `return` in `map()` function?

Comment: Try `var availableItems = [<?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>];` (i.e. enclose with brackets).

Comment: There are 30k rows so I won't bore you with everything, but console.log(availableItems) returns "["0-47310|EVAX MODULE COVER PLATE|REV XX", "0-47320|EVAX SPLITTER MOUNTING PLATE|REV 2", "0146-046|Cap SM 0.000033uF 50V 5%|AVX 12065A330JAT", "0146-050|Cap SM 0.22uF 50V 10%|AVX 12105C224KAT*A..."]" and console.log(elem) returns the same data, with each element on it's own line.

Comment: You may have lead me closer to the problem. I noticed after 20 or so lines of the elem output, there is a NULL value. I don't understand how that's possible if the primary key of the table is NOT NULL. I ran a query searching for NULL on item_no and there are no results.

Comment: The JSON data is showing NULL values on record 24 & 25. I've looked through samplings of the other 30k+ rows (Chrome groups them into 100's) and there are no other NULL values showing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being non-ascii characters stored in the database. Once I removed them, everything worked as expected. Thanks for everyone's help